# Using rack middleware in a class based sinatra application with async request

Tags: logging, sinatra, rack, eventmachine

I'm trying to log async requests to my sinatra app. I'm using sinatra synchrony which is working great, but I don't see any of my request info. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427033/how-do-i-log-asynchronous-thinsinatrarack-requests) shows a solution to this but my sorry newb self is unable to get it to work!

app.rb

```
require_relative 'logger' # middleware

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Synchrony # async http requests up in this!
  use Logger::Middleware
  ...
end
```

On rackup I get:

```
/Users/nflacco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:197:in `<top (required)>': Logger is not a class (TypeError)
```

I looked around a little bit but I didn't see a quick answer on using middleware with a class based sinatra app. Thanks!

---

Update: I messed around a little with Rack:CommonLogger and got it to show my requests to the server (even with sinatra-synchrony) but nothing was getting written to file. Hmmmmm.

app.rb

```
  configure do
    Dir.mkdir('log') unless File.exists?('log')
    use Rack::CommonLogger, Logger.new('log/elphi-api.log')
  end
```

Comment: Are you implementing a separate `Logger` class that is in `logger.rb`?

Comment: No, it's a module with a class inside it called Logger

Comment: Let me clarify- per the other post, it's a module called Logger that contains a class called Middleware

Comment: Regarding your update, this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239240/use-rackcommonlogger-in-sinatra